# Detect forwards delete in html input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a input field like so:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')

input.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  const keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which
  
  if (keyCode === /* BACKSPACE */ 8) {
    console.log('pressed backspace')
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

That snippet detects when the user presses backspace, except for a weird reason I only want to detect when the user does a backwards delete thing (which is alt+backspace on chromebook), which instead of deleting the character before the caret, it deletes the character after the caret. I'm looking for a cross browser and cross platform way to do this (as all devices have different keybindings for it)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The difficulty is that different browsers handle keyboard events differently.

Comment: @AlexanderShtang Not necessarily, all browsers implement keyCode or which, and in ES6+ you can use event.key === 'KeyA', etc.

Comment: I might be missing something, but what you are describing sounds like the Delete key. Have you tried just capturing that? if (key === "Delete") or keycode==46

Comment: No, I mean backwards delete which is when you press alt+delete (on chromebook), on mac and windows its different. Basically in a textbox instead of deleting the character before the caret, it deletes the character after the caret. Please read the question.

Comment: Chromebook has this shortcut because it only has a backspace key, but other computer keyboards normally have delete keys and Alt+Backspace does something else. So just check for Alt+Backspace on Chromebook and Delete on everything else?

Comment: mac has it supported natively, i just forgot the keys

Comment: It seems the feature is called **forward delete**. On iOS it's `Function (fn) + Delete`, and also `Control + D`